# Recognize the type of webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I need to implement a client application to consume the services provided by "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/webservices/en/". But I am not able to determine whether these are WSDL based services or Rest web services. So how we decide at the client side that what type of services being provided by the server?? Please provide suggestions or helpful links in this regards?

Comment: Anybody any suggestions how can I start working towards it.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the examples given there, its a RESTful web services.  For example,

The URL `http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/geoinfo/ws/countryNames/MEX` requests the `countryNames` whose 3 char ISO3 code is `MEX`

It produces an XML output. Your simplest client will simply invoke this URL and parse the xml received.

Comment: Go or JAX-RS which is specifically for Restful services.